# Proper name of AngularJS project

Tags: angularjs

What is the proper name of the [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) project? Its homepage uses "AngularJS", in other places it is referred to as "Angular" (capital A) and in a lot of places it is spelled "angular" (in lowercase form).

For instance, in [Getting Started](http://docs.angularjs.org/misc/started): "The **angular** compiler is fully extensible, meaning that with **angular** you can build your own declarative language on top of HTML!"

I'm specially interested to know if the lowercase form is the "official" one, since it seems to be the most used in the documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The official name is "AngularJS." It's often referred to as just "angular" for brevity.